# Displaying links in a table viewer

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I want to display clickable links as column values in a table viewer. All I am getting is plain text now.
Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create draw label provider and draw the text to look like a hyperlink and act on the click event with a mouse-listener. [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet049StyledCellLabelProvider) is an example